# python argparse corss sub-command option

Tags: python, argparse

using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), i am trying to create an optional argument which is available globally (in all commands and sub-commands).

for instance, setting a `--verbose` optional argument. in the same way that `--help` is available by default.

the following snippet only works for me in the non-subcommand

```py
parser.add_argument(
  '-v', '--verbose',
  help='verbose',
  type=bool,
  default=False,
  action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction
)
```

how can it be done?

Comment: That's not a snippet. That's a line of code. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do not specify `type=bool`.  `bool('false')` does not yield `False`.  Use `action='store_true'` if you want a simple True/False value.

Answer (score 1):

Each parser, main and sub, gets an automatic `help` argument (unless you specify `add_help=False`).  Further more a '-h' exits right away after displaying its message.  So if the '-h' is before the subcommand string, you see the main help.  If after you see that subcommand's help.

To make a command like '-v' available both in the main and the sub parsers, you have to define it in all parsers.  The `parents` can streamline that.  But this has problems, as @Alex points out.  The `default` value for the subcommand overrides any value set in the main (default or user).

You can get around this by specifying a different `dest` for the main and the subs.  You can still use the same '-v', but the values will be in different attributes in `args`.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose', action='store_true')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
sp1.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='subverbose')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

sample runs:

```
0925:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py -h
usage: stack65773318.py [-h] [-v] {cmd1} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd1}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose
0928:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py cmd1 -h
usage: stack65773318.py cmd1 [-h] [-v]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose
0928:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py -v
Namespace(cmd=None, verbose=True)
0928:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py -v cmd1
Namespace(cmd='cmd1', subverbose=False, verbose=True)
0928:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py cmd1 -v
Namespace(cmd='cmd1', subverbose=True, verbose=False)
0928:~/mypy$ python3 stack65773318.py -v cmd1 -v
Namespace(cmd='cmd1', subverbose=True, verbose=True)
```

Comment: That's neat, I didn't even think to use an alternate dest. Very nice!

Comment: correct me if i wrong, `verbose` had to be defined more than once (in each subcommand) and i wanted to avoid this.

Comment: One way or other you have to define an argument for each parser, main or sub.  There are ways of saving typing for common ones, but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents) like so:

```py
import argparse

base_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
base_parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="verbose", action="store_true")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[base_parser])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser("sub", parents=[base_parser])
parser_1.add_argument("--foo", help="Some opt")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

What this generates:

```sh
~ python args.py -h
usage: args.py [-h] [-v] {sub} ...

positional arguments:
  {sub}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose

~ python args.py sub -h
usage: args.py sub [-h] [-v] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose
  --foo FOO      Some opt
```

This method requires the `-v` flag be used after the sub-command, though.

```sh
~ python args.py sub -v --foo 9
Namespace(verbose=True, foo='9')   # -v is recognised

~ python args.py -v sub --foo 9
Namespace(verbose=False, foo='9')  # -v is not recognised
```

Comment: The subcommand's `default` is overriding the main value, whether default or user provided.  Subcommand arguments need different `dest` to avoid this problem.